# How to execute a javascript file across protocols/schemes?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I was able to execute the following Greasemonkey in local HTML file:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @include     file:///C:/fx/test/a.html
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var scriptElement = document.createElement( "script" );
scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
scriptElement.src = "file://c:/fx/alert.js";
document.head.appendChild( scriptElement );
```

I was able to execute the following in localhost:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        testWeb
// @include     http://localhost/test/a.html
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var scriptElement = document.createElement( "script" );
scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
scriptElement.src = "http://localhost/test/alert.js";
document.head.appendChild( scriptElement );
```

However, I was not able to execute the following.
There is HTML file in web server and there is script file in local drive.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        testWeb
// @include     http://localhost/test/a.html
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var scriptElement = document.createElement( "script" );
scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
scriptElement.src = "file://c:/fx/alert.js";
document.head.appendChild( scriptElement );
```

`greasemonkey.fileIsGreaseable` was set to true in about:config.
What should I do to execute a local script file in script tag?

Comment: What if you add `// @include     file:///C:/fx/test/a.html` to your last sample?

Comment: You are trying to access the file system across domains.  Its just not allowed in most browsers.

Comment: `fileIsGreaseable` just means greasemonkey will run your scripts even when you visit a `file://` url in the browser (normally it only intercepts `http://` and `https://`).

Comment: There's probably an API you can use to read the script file yourself, then stuff its contents in `scriptElement.textContent` and append that.

Comment: The script file which I want to use is very big.
Therefore it is difficult to use scriptElement.textContent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a basic security error to try and load resources across protocols like that.  Try to imagine the unspeakable evil a malicious website (or its 3rd party ad) could (and did) do if it could just load `file://` resources.

For this reason, the browser will block such attempts across protocols with messages like:

> Security Error: Content at `http://evil.com/pwner.htm` may not load or link to file:///C:/user_passwords.db

(Firefox)

---

You already know what you have to do:

- When the script runs against a `file://` protocol page, access your resource with the `file://` protocol.
- When the script runs against an `http(s)` protocol page, access your resource with the `http(s)` protocol.